# Cakephp 3.x trying to view Uploaded images results in Missing Controller Error

Tags: php, cakephp, server, cakephp-3.0

I have an image located at webroot/uploads/profiles/partner_1/bg_image.jpg

When I attempt to display an uploaded image located at:
uploads/profiles/partner_1/bg_image.jpg

I get the Error:

> Error: UploadsController could not be found.

What makes this particularly frustrating is that this same application is working on my local dev server, and only fails when I move it up to production. I feel like there must be some simple solution that I'm just missing as I stress over deadlines.

The .htaccess file is unmodified but follows:

```
# Uncomment the following to prevent the httpoxy vulnerability
# See: https://httpoxy.org/
#<IfModule mod_headers.c>
#    RequestHeader unset Proxy
#</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

I experimented placing the target file in different directories down the path..  It seems to be a factor of **directory depth**.

I can find the file in:
    /uploads, 
    /uploads/profiles, 
    /img, 
    /img/uploads,

Basically anything more then 2 directories deeper then webroot fails.

Comment: Are your vhosts defined identically in Apache? I can't see your whole codebase, and I am not familiar with Cake, but I would be inclined to get a stack trace on that error to see where the entry-point is. Finding out why PHP is invoked at all would be useful, if your local machine just renders a static asset.

Comment: Post your `.htaccess` file in your question. We can't help you without it.

Comment: Are you displaying image with the Cake's Html helper($this->Html->image())???, if YES then there is an issue in your path and if NO then post your .htaccess

Comment: .htaccess is unmodified but adding it to the post.  I can use the HTML helper to display static images in the webroot/img directory, I can also just type the url and see those images.  I cannot connect to or see the webroot/uploads directory, instead I get the missing controller.

Comment: Adding more to question above... not an answer yet, but a clue.

Comment: Verify that the directory permissions are for the Apache user and that Apache has permissions to read from those directories.

Answer (score 1):

You have no condition in your rewrite rule to exclude existing files.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I don't recognise your `.htaccess` file as anything from any previous release of CakePHP. That doesn't mean it's wrong, but all releases have rewritten the URL to the `index.php` file.

Comment: The file you're showing here is exactly the same as the one located in my webroot folder now.  The one I posted before was from the application root. Is there a change I could make to the webroot file to specifically tell it to treat its uploads directory as a basic directory?

Comment: I've added to my question above, the issue seems to be an issue with directory depth, that if I go too deep it fails. Could a series of new .htaccess files be the answer?

Comment: I'm going to guess that the permissions on the files are wrong after it is moved from being uploaded.

Comment: Permissions on all Directories are 755, for all files 644, these are the same for the files at closer directories that I can load.

Comment: @Grockell and for completeness. The new uploaded files are assigned to the `www-data:www-data` user?

Comment: I'm not certain in Filezilla their Owner/Group for everything is listed as:
12300790 859340

Comment: It does seem to be an issue with my dynamically created folders.  I went in and set one of them to 777 through filezilla and had no issue loading the image within. Client meeting this morning, so I'm simply recursively opening up my uploads folders.  Later today, I'll come in and find a real solution. Thank you so much for helping me get here.

Comment: You should log into the server with SSH and use the command line tools to verify everything. Filezilla is not a shell tool.